# 401 unauthorized error when opening the URL of my Google Cloud Run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I built a sample container(sample of Go, https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) and deployed to cloud run (I unchecked "allow unauthenticated invocations").

However, when I open the endpoint URL of my service, I get a 401 page,

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

- According to the official document (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating#developers), I used this command.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud config config-helper --format 'value(credential.id_token)')" [SERVICE_URL]
```

- My user account has "roles/run.invoker"
- When I checked "allow unauthenticated invocations", I got an expected result.

Is there anything to open the endpoint?

Comment: Which account are you using `gcloud auth list`? The account with the asterisk must be authorized in Cloud Run. You can also run `gcloud config config-helper` and double check the `core/account` property.

Comment: Also, for Cloud Run I think 401 means an error with authorization (bad / wrong credentials). 403 means not authorized (no credentials). I don't have a reference, just my own experience testing Cloud Run.

Comment: Can you run it with `curl -v` to see the headers? One of the headers is supposed to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: > John Hanley 
Using account has "roles/run.invoker". I confirmed it by `gcloud auth list` and `gcloud config config-helper`

Comment: > AhmetB

`www-authenticate` header is this
`Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"`
I know that authentication has failed, but I do not know why.
I can get ID token by `gcloud config config-helper --format 'value(credential.id_token)'`

Comment: What is your gcloud version (gcloud --version)? Can you make sure it's at least 243.0.0. ?

Comment: @wlhee
Thank you for your advice !!
I used Google Cloud Shell and its gcloud version is 242.0.0.
I got an expected result when using my local machine.

Comment: Np! Cloud shell still has another issue. We are fixing it in the next release!

Comment: If possible, please post the comment as answer.

Comment: [Updated] Using gcloud in Cloud Shell to call authentication-required Cloud Run service is also working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please make sure gcloud version is at least 243.0.0 by "gcloud --version"
2. Please use "gcloud components update" to update if gcloud is too old
3. [Updated] Using gcloud in Cloud Shell to call authentication-required Cloud Run service is also working now.

Thanks!

Comment: When i run `gcloud config config-helper --format 'value(credential.id_token)'` in Cloud Shell that token doesn't work with Cloud Run outside of Cloud Shell. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: @rinderwahn sorry, what does "doesn't work with cloud run outside of cloud shell" mean?

Comment: Cloud Shell returns a different token than my local `gcloud` command even when using the same version which is `248.0.0` for me in both environments. What i meant is that copying the token from Cloud Shell and using it e.g. with Postman didn't work for me as well as several people i know (yesterday). Interestingly i just tried it out again and now it seems to work just fine.

Comment: It is expected that the tokens are different when generated in Cloud shell vs local machine. Both should work. It would be helpful to know the http error code when it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect from a cloud function, finally, after 15-minute wrestling with the same 401 error when invoking a cloud run service that does not allow unauthenticated invocations:

```
import google.auth

auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, URL)

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + id_token,
               "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
response = requests.post(URL, json=request_json, headers=headers)
```